# How to pass extra data to an ajax success event?

Tags: ajax, jquery

How to pass extra data to an ajax success event?

```
var extra_data = 'some data';
var a = {
    type : 'post',
    async : true,
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 15000,
    contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    global : true,
    url : url,
    success : [
        function(response, textStatus, jqXHR, extra_data){

        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: like what? Where would this  data come from?

Comment: then why wud u want to pass it as an argument? it shud be available in the scope right? You could just access it in the body of the success handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just declare extra_data as a global variable if i remember (without var before) and you can use it inside the scope of the success method, and you don't need to pass it through methods arguments

```
extra_data = 'some data';
var a = {
 type : 'post',
 async : true,
 cache : false,
 dataType : 'json',
 timeout : 15000,
 contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
 global : true,
 url : url,
 success : [
     function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
       console.log(extra_data); //for example
     }
 ]
};
```

Comment: This completely breaks the scope encapsulation.  If there were multiple AJAX requests using a shared success handler, that global variable would be shared as well and it would completely break.  Instead, you can probably add data directly to the jqXHR object in the beforeSend handler, which provides access to the jqXHR object before the request is initiated.